# Deploying a WSP to SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, solution-package

I have the WSP deployed in the Solution Management but when I go to the Site Collection Features it's not listed there for me to Activate.

Comment: I assume that you are trying to activate a feature that should be contained in your solution package. Are you sure that said feature is defined at site collection level scope?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure of two things, is the WSP deployed to the web application that has the site collection? also is you feature scoped to Site?

Answer (score 0):

Your feature may be hidden. Search for your feature running this script:

```
Get-SPFeature | Sort -Property Scope, Hidden, DisplayName | FT -GroupBy Scope DisplayName, Hidden ,Id > c:\AllInstalledFeatures.txt
```

In the root of C: you'll find the file AllInstalledFeatures.txt which displays every feature you got in your farm, if the feature is hidden or not and its ID. Search for your feature there.

Ref: [PowerShell Commands To List SharePoint Features](http://www.glynblogs.com/2010/08/powershell-commands-to-list-sharepoint-features.html)